# Storage level Origin

Tags: origin, pallet-collective

We have a DAO factory, and the whole idea is to create councils dynamically on the pallet level.
The best would be using the native approach of the council origin but having the possibility to change the council through extrinsic calls instead of having instances of the `pallet_collective` at the runtime level.
I think it's currently not possible, but still, I wonder what's the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do things which aren't really supported in the Rust type system.

Instead you should probably re-create some kind of access control layer into your pallet which can be dynamically created and managed. For example some kind of simple multisig structure.

In this case, the Rust type system is not going to be friendly to spinning up multiple origins which can be manipulated by storage.